# Jolie and Spring Boot annotations - how can it be done?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jolie

I am currently working on creating basic Jolie support in Spring Boot. Jolie is a microservice language, which under the hood - is based on Java, but has very different syntax([example](https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/getting-started/creating_service_and_client)). Thanks to [JavaService](https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/technology-integration/javaservices) class, which comes with Jolie, it is possible to take class/method functionalities from Java and its libraries, and embed them in Jolie. I would like to know how can the same be achieved for annotations and functionalities that are implemented through them. Can it be done with JavaService, too? Or do I have to write my own annotation parsing for Jolie?

A simple example of behaviour I'd like to achieve is a @SpringBootApplication which runs a "Hello world" @RestController, like [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example/)(points 2.3 and 2.4). Ideally, similar program in Jolie would look somewhat like below:

```
interface SpringAppInterface {
    OneWay:
      run(string)
}

outputPort SpringApplication {
    Interfaces: SpringAppInterface
}

embedded {
    Java:
      "joliex.spring-boot.SpringApplicationService" in SpringApplication
}

@SpringBootApplication
main {
    run@SpringApplication(args)
}
```

where SpringApplicationService extends the JavaService class and is embedded in Jolie. And now a @RestController:

```
inputPort SpringTestService {
    ...
}

@RestController
main {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    hello(void)(response) {
        response = "hello world"
    }
}
```

That is an ideal way and it presents well a behaviour I want to achieve. And to better show a real use of JavaService class - [here](https://github.com/jolie/jolie/blob/master/javaServices/coreJavaServices/src/joliex/util/MathService.java) is its implementation of standard Java Math class and [here](https://github.com/jolie/jolie/blob/master/include/math.iol) - its embedment in Jolie.

On a side note: I wonder if it's possible to run whole Spring Boot logic on the JavaService side, so for example I would have a JavaService already annotated with @SpringBootApplication, a JavaService annotated @RestController etc.

---

**Edit:** 
As I said - I want to create Jolie support in Spring Boot, so in the end a Jolie developer would be able to include, for example "spring-boot.iol", and be able to create Spring Boot-based Jolie programs. "spring-boot.iol" I imagine would be similar to all existing include files, like "console.iol", "math.iol" etc., and it would embed a JavaService - let's call it "SpringBootService". Now this SpringBootService would take functionalities from Spring Boot libraries to allow Jolie to use them. That way - with inclusion of some *.iol files - a Jolie program would indeed implement Spring Boot functionalities and run Spring Boot applications.
[image]
That is of course only my concept - how I think this task might be done, but then again - there is the problem of Spring Boot annotations.

Comment: Can you please include a brief example (possibly with code) of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you. Question edited.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things a bit more, but I would like to have a bit more information to be sure I understand what you want to do.

Is it the case that:
 
A) you have a Spring program and you want to call the exposed methods via http from a Jolie program or 

B) you have some Java methods that *happen* to be reachable via http requests through Spring, but what you really want is to be able to invoke those Java methods from a Jolie program (e.g., independently from the fact they are reachable via http) .

Comment: In the end, I want to be able to create simple Spring Boot applications only with Jolie. To achieve that, I will write Java methods, which indeed will be visible to Jolie - thanks to JavaService. These Java methods would implement key Spring Boot functionalities. Jolie would then invoke those Java methods, resulting in Jolie implementing Spring Boot functionalities. Also edited question: added real example of JavaService use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to run the Jolie interpreter from Java, inside of your Spring Boot application. See, for example, http://fmontesi.github.io/2015/01/30/running-jolie-inside-of-java.html

Declare a local memory input port in your Jolie service: https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/locations/local

You can then reach the operations exposed on the local input port by calling `interpreter.commCore().getLocalCommChannel()`, which will return you a communication channel object that you can use to send and receive messages to the Jolie interpreter.

Here's a quick and dirty example (you probably want to handle the future and exceptions better) where I send a value containing an integer "x":

```
Value v = Value.create();
v.setFirstChild( "x", 5 );
CommMessage request = CommMessage.createRequest( "yourOperationName", "/", v );
LocalCommChannel c = interpreter.commCore().getLocalCommChannel();
try {
    c.send( request );
    CommMessage response = c.recvResponseFor( request ).get();
    if ( response.isFault() ) {
        throw response.fault();
    }
    return response.value();
} catch( ExecutionException | InterruptedException | IOException e ) {
    throw new FaultException( Constants.IO_EXCEPTION_FAULT_NAME, e );
}
```

This API is actually still not used a lot outside of the internals of the Interpreter and Java services for Jolie, so comments on making it friendlier are always welcome.

PS: What's your motivation for this? If your objective is to make a microservice with Jolie, isn't it just easier to add the functionalities you need as a Jolie library instead of "adding Jolie to Spring Boot"?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong - your suggestion is to run Jolie program from Spring Boot, using Interpreter class and communication classes for messaging, AND the rest is as I described earlier - Jolie program embeds a JavaService which imports Spring Boot functionalities for use in Jolie. That way, annotations would be handled on their normal Spring Boot side and Jolie would still be able to use imported Spring Boot methods. PS: This is my Engineer's degree project ("Extending Spring Boot to support Jolie").

Comment: Exactly. You make a spring boot application, where you can use the normal annotations. This application uses a Jolie interpreter internally to pass messages on to the Jolie program. The Jolie program then accesses spring boot functionalities through a Java service as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Jolie and Spring expose the accessibility to Java methods in different ways.

Since you are considering Spring, you are focusing on a specific case: HTTP.

To archieve a similar result with Jolie, you can follow what is done in [1], where there are details on the mapping of HTTP URLs into Jolie operations.

In your case, where you have the path /hello that coincides with the name of the Java method, Jolie automatically converts the http request into a request towards an operation called "hello".

Then what you need to do is:

- let your Java class extend the JavaService class;
- compile and embed the compiled java class into an outputPort, e.g., `myJavaService` whose interface exposes the operation `hello`;
- use the `Aggregates` [2] keyword to let the inputPort automatically redirect the call for operation `hello` to the outputPort `myJavaService`, which can satisfy one such request.

For more clarity, I tried to draw the schema below

```
        ┌───────────────────────┐                      
        │ Jolie                 │                      
        │ Service               │                      
        │                       │                      
────────┼▶ inputPort (http)     │                      
        │   - /hello ──────┐    │                      
        │┌── - hello ◀─────┘    │                      
        ││  - aggregates        │                      
        │└──▶- myJavaSrv──────┐ │                      
        │┌────────────────────┘ │   ┌─────────────────┐
        ││ outputPort myJavaSvr │   │                 │
        │└─▶- hello ────────┐   │   │   Java Service  │
        │                   └───┼───┼▶- hello         │
        │                       │   │                 │
        │                       │   └─────────────────┘
        └───────────────────────┘
```

If you want to change how you expose that operation to your users (e.g., via other media than socket or other protocols, e.g., jsonrpc, xmlrpc, soap, etc.) you just need to change the setting in the inputPort. On the other side, if you want to modify how the `hello` operation is implemented (by another Java service, by a Jolie service, by a Javascript service, etc.) you just need to modify where the outputPort points to (an embedded service, an external one, etc.).

On the contrary, Spring only exposes your methods via HTTP and the routes are annotated (and scattered) in your java code.

```
                                                    

        ┌────────────────┐       ┌─────────────────┐
        │                │       │  Java Class +   │
        │                │       │  Spring         │
   ─────┼────────────────┼───────▶  Annotations    │
        │     Spring     │       │                 │
        │   Bootstrap    │       │ @\hello         │
        │                │       │  - hello        │
        └────────────────┘       └─────────────────┘
```

[1] Process-aware web programming with Jolie. Fabrizio Montesi. (2016). Sci. Comput. Program., 130, 69–96. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.scico.2016.05.002

[2] https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/architectural-composition/aggregation

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely helpful. If I understand correctly, you are showing how to write a Jolie program that behaves similarly to a Spring Boot program, but without really any use of Spring Boot. I will actually have to let its real functionalities(also meaning annotations like @SpringBootApplication, @RestController) into Jolie - probably through JavaServices. Question is - can JavaService handle all these requirements and how - basically off course?

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly.
However, I do not understand instead what you mean by "I will actually have to let its real functionalities into Jolie".
Probably an example of execution, similar to what I have tried to go through in my answer (schemas are a plus :)) could help me understand your use case.

Comment: By that I meant, that I do not want a Jolie program to act like a Spring Boot program - I want it to also be a Spring Boot program - well.. under the hood at least. I edited the question. Hope it helps ;)