# Unknown operation error when running Jolie program using Interpreter in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jolie

Not long ago I got an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549113/jolie-and-spring-boot-annotations-how-can-it-be-done) question on how to combine Jolie and Spring Boot functionalities. I've tried to implement the suggested solution, using LocalCommChannel class and local inputPort in Jolie, but unfortunately an operation that I am passing in request is not recognized. Below are my Spring Boot Application, simple controller that tries to run the Interpreter and a Jolie program.

#### App.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### HelloController.java

```java
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String hello() {
        String jh = System.getenv( "JOLIE_HOME" );
        String arg[] = new String[]{
            "-l",
            ".\\lib\\*;$JOLIE_HOME\\lib;$JOLIE_HOME\\javaServices\\*;$JOLIE_HOME\\extensions\\*".replace("$JOLIE_HOME", jh),
            "-i",
            "$JOLIE_HOME\\include".replace("$JOLIE_HOME", jh),
            "main.ol"
        };
        try {
            final Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(arg, HelloController.class.getClassLoader(), null);

            Value v = Value.create();
            v.setFirstChild( "number", 5 );
            CommMessage request = CommMessage.createRequest( "twice", "/", v );
            LocalCommChannel c = interpreter.commCore().getLocalCommChannel();
            c.send( request );
            CommMessage response = c.recvResponseFor( request );
            if ( response.isFault() ) {
                System.out.println("thrown response.fault()");
                throw response.fault();
            }
            return response.value().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Bad result";
    }
}
```

#### main.ol

```
include "console.iol"
include "runtime.iol"

execution { concurrent }

type TwiceRequest: void {
    .number: int
}

type TwiceResponse: void {
    .result: int
}

interface LocalInterface {
    RequestResponse:
        twice(TwiceRequest)(TwiceResponse)
}

inputPort TwiceIP {
    Location: "local"
    Interfaces: LocalInterface
}

init
{
    getLocalLocation@Runtime()( TwiceIP.location )
}

main {
    [twice( request )( response )] {
        println@Console("Hello World")();
        response.result = request.number * 2
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
2019-07-07 18:20:53.315  WARN 19236 --- [       Thread-3] Jolie : [main.ol] Received 
a message for operation twice, not specified in the input port LocalInputPort 
at the receiving service. Sending IOException to the caller.
thrown response.fault()
jolie.runtime.FaultException: IOException: Invalid operation: twice
    at jolie.net.CommCore$CommChannelHandlerRunnable.handleMessage(CommCore.java:594)
    at jolie.net.CommCore$CommChannelHandlerRunnable.run(CommCore.java:620)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried to track which Jolie classes and functions my program goes through and I noticed that when getLocalCommChannel() is called, it creates new LocalListener which creates totally new and empty-interfaced InputPort, so I don't know how *twice* operation would be visible. I suspect I might have to maybe use addLocalInputPort() in CommCore or mergeInterface() in LocalListener and configure things myself, but I hoped Jolie can take care of this without my action.

PS: Is there any online documentation for those Jolie core Java classes or the best and only option is to read the code on github?

Comment: Seems clashes of packages that are called twice, please try to make sure you about the packages.

Comment: There's no online documentation for the internal Java classes. We'd be thrilled to receive contributions for that. :-)

Comment: PS: But you can look at the javadocs and improve them. We could just publish those for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java code:

- You're not using replaceAll, nor escaping the $ as I was doing in my original post: http://fmontesi.github.io/2015/01/30/running-jolie-inside-of-java.html
- You're not starting the interpreter. There's actually a new fancier interface since I wrote my original blog post: you can call interpreter.start(), which returns a future that you can wait on until the interpreter is ready to receive messages.

In the Jolie code:

- You don't need to invoke Runtime to use the local location.
- You put the computation for the request-response operation `twice` after you send the response (notice where you put the square brackets).

Here's an example that works for me. Notice that I'm using : instead of ; as path separator in the arguments (I'm testing on Linux), you might need to change that.

## Example.java

```
public class Example
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String jh = System.getenv( "JOLIE_HOME" );
        String arg[] = {
            "-l",
            "./lib/*:$JOLIE_HOME/lib:$JOLIE_HOME/javaServices/*:$JOLIE_HOME/extensions/*".replaceAll("\\$JOLIE_HOME", jh),
            "-i",
            "$JOLIE_HOME/include".replaceAll("\\$JOLIE_HOME", jh),
            "main.ol"
        };
        try {
            final Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(arg, Example.class.getClassLoader(), null);
            Exception e = interpreter.start().get();
            if ( e != null )
                throw e;

            Value v = Value.create();
            v.setFirstChild( "number", 5 );
            CommMessage request = CommMessage.createRequest( "twice", "/", v );
            LocalCommChannel c = interpreter.commCore().getLocalCommChannel();
            c.send( request );
            CommMessage response = c.recvResponseFor( request ).get();
            if ( response.isFault() ) {
                System.out.println("thrown response.fault()");
                throw response.fault();
            }
            System.out.println( response.value().getFirstChild( "result" ).strValue() );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## main.ol

```
include "console.iol"

execution { concurrent }

type TwiceRequest: void {
    .number: int
}

type TwiceResponse: void {
    .result: int
}

interface LocalInterface {
    RequestResponse:
        twice(TwiceRequest)(TwiceResponse)
}

inputPort TwiceIP {
    Location: "local"
    Interfaces: LocalInterface
}

main {
    [twice( request )( response ) {
        println@Console("Hello World")();
        response.result = request.number * 2
    }]
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. What was wrong was of course my bad use of square brackets in Jolie program and not running the interpreter. The odd thing is that when I try to run it the way described on your blog - with use of Thread - it still didn't work - same output as before, but using the fancy new way did the trick. :) Also, the way I replaced $JOLIE_HOME in paths works for me - maybe because of a different environment (I work in VS Code on Windows 10).

Comment: I actually managed to run the interpreter and make it work using Thread - as described in your blog - but I had to put a sleep after t.start(), before Value.create().

Comment: Glad it helped! And yes, the main problem with the "manual" thread approach is that you don't get to know when the interpreter is ready to receive messages (parsing the Jolie program and initialising its input ports takes a very brief moment). The only way was to make the Jolie program itself notify you somehow (with a message or through a java service). The new start method fixes all that.